# Represent a condition where the value of the JSpinner is not empty

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I need to represent a condition where the value of the JSpinner is not empty. The following statement seems to be not working properly:

```
if (!timeSpinner.getValue().equals(null)) { ...}
```

Comment: *"not working properly:"*  Maybe it is just lazy.  Try giving it a good flogging.  If that fails to make it work properly, you might instead.  1) Describe what you expected to happen 2) Describe what actually happened.  (With copy/pasted error messages as appropriate)  But as general advice.  1) Ask a question.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) and [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) it would seem you're generally not allowed to have `null` as a value. An exception is thrown when constructing the model, and when setting the new value, if that value is `null`.

You could create your own [`SpinnerModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html) and handle the condition yourself.